# YA fantasy about girl who finds enchanted monster protectors and saves a prince in an ice castle?

Tags: story-identification

Read this in the 80's, think it was a series of books. A girl travels from land to land, once protected by different mythical beasts, now missing. She befriends ugly creatures along the way ( one of them she calls Mooncalf?). Eventually, she finds a prince under a spell in an ice castle, who can't remember who he is and has been turned into a monster, I think. Once the spell is lifted the creatures turn out to be the missing protectors of the land and the prince gets his memory back. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Darkangel - that's the one! Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer below (click on the checkmark to the left) to mark this question as 'solved'.

Answer (score 1):

The [Darkangel Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkangel_Trilogy) by Meredith Ann Pierce. Books are;

- **The Darkangel**
- **A Gathering Of Gargoyles**
- **The Pearl At The Soul Of The World.**

The prince has been turned into a type of vampire by a wicked witch, and steals girls to drink their souls.

Comment: Is there a mooncalf or a girl traveling from land to land? What about this book series makes you think it's the one described?